# Como salvar varios radiobuttons no banco MySql?

Tags: php, html

Galera, preciso salvar varios grupos de radiobuttons no banco. Exemplo:

```
<input type="radio" value="sim" name="grupo1">
<input type="radio" value="nao" name="grupo1">

<input type="radio" value="sim" name="grupo2">
<input type="radio" value="nao" name="grupo2">

<input type="radio" value="sim" name="grupo3">
<input type="radio" value="nao" name="grupo3">
```

São 3 grupos diferentes  preciso salvar o valor do radio escolhido de cada grupo no banco.

Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Galera, esqueci de falar. Os grupos de radio são dinamicos dependendo da pagina carregada. Dependendo podem aparecer 3 grupos, 4 grupos, 120 grupos. O problema é esse. Tenho que pegar o valor de cada grupo que aparecer quando carregar a pagina.

Comment: Resolvido. Criei um for() pra listar todos os radios e capturar os valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago Quando você submeter o formulário o valor enviado é apenas o do radio selecionado.
Isso porque o grupo de radio tem o mesmo `name`

Você pode testar assim:

```
<form action="">
    <p>Pergunta 01</p>
    <label for="">Sim</label><input type="radio" value="sim" name="grupo1" required="">
    <label for="">Não</label><input type="radio" value="nao" name="grupo1" required="">
    <br><br>
    <p>Pergunta 02</p>
    <label for="">Sim</label><input type="radio" value="sim" name="grupo2" required="">
    <label for="">Não</label><input type="radio" value="nao" name="grupo2" required="">
    <br><br>
    <p>Pergunta 03</p>
    <label for="">Sim</label><input type="radio" value="sim" name="grupo3" required="">
    <label for="">Não</label><input type="radio" value="nao" name="grupo3" required="">

    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
<?php 
    if ($_GET){
        echo "<p>Pergunta 01: </p> " . $_GET['grupo1'];
        echo "<p>Pergunta 02: </p> " . $_GET['grupo2'];
        echo "<p>Pergunta 03: </p> " . $_GET['grupo3'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentario. Realmente assim funciona. Adicionei um comentario a minha pergunta. Esqueci de cocoar uma observação.

Answer (score 0):

Boas, não sei se percebi bem a tua pergunta no entanto cá vai..

Podes por exemplo no "value" de cada "radio", colocar 0 ou 1, sendo que consideras o 0 como não e o 1 como sim. A partir daí é jogar com estes 2 valores quando o valor é 1 marcas quando é 0 ignoras. Para cada grupo usas um género de ID único.

Exemplo mysql:

```
***************
page_id ------ group_id ------ radio
***************
page1 --------- group1 --------- 0
page1 --------- group2 --------- 1
page2 --------- group3 --------- 0
page2 --------- group4 --------- 0
```

Podes usar a mesma tabela em varias paginas com vários grupos, quando fazes o select para carregar usas "WHERE page_id == pagina que queres".

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentario. Realmente assim funciona. Adicionei um comentario a minha pergunta. Esqueci de cocoar uma observação.

Comment: Mesmo que tenhas 120 grupos continua a ser a mesma coisa, basta que cada grupo tenha um ID único... Podes também adicionar um campo no mysql para destingir a página. Vou editar o exemplo de cima.